# How to avoid redundant code when implementing Index and IndexMut in Rust

Tags: rust

At the moment, implementing the `std::ops::IndexMut` trait on a type in Rust requires that I also implement the `std::ops::Index` trait as well. The bodies of these implementations end up being virtually identical. For example:

```
use std::ops::{Index, IndexMut};

enum IndexType {
    A,
    B,
}

struct Indexable {
    a: u8,
    b: u8,
}

impl Index<IndexType> for Indexable {
    type Output = u8;
    fn index<'a>(&'a self, idx: IndexType) -> &'a u8 {
        match idx {
            IndexType::A => &self.a,
            IndexType::B => &self.b,
        }
    }
}

impl IndexMut<IndexType> for Indexable {
    fn index_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, idx: IndexType) -> &'a mut u8 {
        match idx {
            IndexType::A => &mut self.a,
            IndexType::B => &mut self.b,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

This works, and obviously for trivial types this isn't a serious problem, but for more complex types with more interesting indexing this quickly becomes laborious and error-prone. I'm scratching my head trying to find a way to unify this code, but nothing is jumping out at me, and yet I feel there has to/should be a way to do this without essentially having to copy and paste. Any suggestions? What am I missing?

Comment: See this discussion https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/parameterisation-over-mutability/235,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this cuts across a few things Rust really isn't good at right now.  The cleanest solution I could come up with was this:

```rust
macro_rules! as_expr {
    ($e:expr) => { $e };
}

macro_rules! borrow_imm { ($e:expr) => { &$e } }
macro_rules! borrow_mut { ($e:expr) => { &mut $e } }

macro_rules! impl_index {
    (
        <$idx_ty:ty> for $ty:ty,
        ($idx:ident) -> $out_ty:ty,
        $($body:tt)*
    ) => {
        impl ::std::ops::Index<$idx_ty> for $ty {
            type Output = $out_ty;
            fn index(&self, $idx: $idx_ty) -> &$out_ty {
                macro_rules! index_expr { $($body)* }
                index_expr!(self, borrow_imm)
            }
        }

        impl ::std::ops::IndexMut<$idx_ty> for $ty {
            fn index_mut(&mut self, $idx: $idx_ty) -> &mut $out_ty {
                macro_rules! index_expr { $($body)* }
                index_expr!(self, borrow_mut)
            }
        }
    };
}

enum IndexType { A, B }

struct Indexable { a: u8, b: u8 }

impl_index! {
    <IndexType> for Indexable,
    (idx) -> u8,
    ($this:expr, $borrow:ident) => {
        match idx {
            IndexType::A => $borrow!($this.a),
            IndexType::B => $borrow!($this.b),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = Indexable { a: 1, b: 2 };
    x[IndexType::A] = 3;
    println!("x {{ a: {}, b: {} }}", x[IndexType::A], x[IndexType::B]);
}
```

The short version is: we turn the body of `index`/`index_mut` into a macro so that we can substitute the name of a *different* macro that, given an expression, expands to *either* `&expr` or `&mut expr`.  We *also* have to re-capture the `self` parameter (using a different name) because `self` is *really weird* in Rust, and I gave up trying to make it work nicely.

Comment: Do you feel that this code is actually better? I wonder what the amount of repetition would need to be before I was like "yeah, this makes it easier to understand" ^_^

Comment: @Shepmaster Well, that *is* the issue.  If anyone comes up with a terser solution, I'd love to see it.

Comment: What are the chances of someone outdoing you, the Master of Macros? ;-)

Comment: @Shepmaster Probably around about the same time Duke Nukem Forever comes out.  ... wait, hang on...

Comment: The macro does look a little goofy, but the more I think about this the more I can see that a macro of some kind really is the right solution here. Thanks!